# How can I create a hash table for key value pairs form a .properties file without including comment lines in file

Tags: powershell

I have a file containing something like the following in a properties file called 'pickles.properties'

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#text here 

#text here
 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

god.ppp.wc.oops=qqq
```

I use a Ps1 to get-content using the following code.

```
 $properties = Get-Content  -Path C:\Scripts\pickled.pinapple.properties
    $properties = [Regex]::Escape($properties -join "`n" )
    $properties =  $properties -replace "\\n", [Environment]::NewLine
    $configuration = ConvertFrom-Stringdata ($properties)
    $configuration
```

I get an error as the following and i don't understand why it is reading my # line as the first value. From what i was reading ConvertFrom-Stringdata should ignore the # sign. also when i printed the $properties file there was no \ before the #.

```
ConvertFrom-Stringdata : Data line '\#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\#' is not in 'name=value' 
format. 
At C:\Scripts\testing properties.ps1:7 char:18
+ $configuration = ConvertFrom-Stringdata ($properties)
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [ConvertFrom-StringData], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromStringDataCommand
```

This is where i printed @configuration

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                                             
\#-------------------------... RFA...
```

Comment: `-replace` is used incorrectly. To replace a linefeed character, the regex character is `\n`. `$properties -replace '\n', [environment]::newline` should be used. If lines are actually ending in backslash and you want to replace that, then you need to escape it. So replacing `\linefeed` is `$properties -replace '\\\n'`. If the properties file is exactly as you have posted, then you only need `gc pickled.pinapple.properties | convertfrom-stringdata`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you need to do the regex/string manipulations that you are doing. You do, however, need to make sure you are using the `-Raw` switch parameter to your `Get-Content` call.

This command works fine in PowerShell v5.1.18362.752 & PowerShell Core v7.0.2.

```bsh
$configuration = Get-Content -Path 'C:\tmp\overflow\63003115\pickles.properties' -Raw | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

It outputs a hashtable of your key/value pairs.

```bsh
PS C:\tmp\overflow\63003115> $configuration = Get-Content -Path 'C:\tmp\overflow\63003115\pickles.properties' -Raw | ConvertFrom-StringData

PS C:\tmp\overflow\63003115> $configuration


Name                           Value
----                           -----
god.ppp.wc.oops                qqq
```